# Laravel shows entire php code as web page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5

I hosted laravel 5 on remote server and I did basic configuration and remove the Internal Server Error issue using virtual host. I have updated server' apache conf file by adding following rules.

```
<Directory "/var/www/server/data/www/example.com/laravel/public">
Allowoverride All
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/server/data/www/example.com/laravel">
Allowoverride All
</Directory>
```

After that it removes Internal Server Error issue. But now the index web page shows entire php code as a webpage. `.htaccess` file in public directory as follows.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

And storage directory have full 777 permission. Where is the problem?

Comment: The request gets not passed to PHP. That's the problem. This can have different causes and writing every single one is too much to answer in a few paragraphs. I suggest you to google it.

Comment: You should install dependencies.
`apt install php-mbstring php-pdo php-tokenizer php-xml php-mcrypt php-gd libapache2-mod-php php-curl php-mysql -y`

and Enable mycrypt 
`phpenmod mcrypt`
and Enable mod_rewrite
`a2enmod  rewrite`